# UI Activity Indicator not working from tableview

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uiactivityindicatorview

The issue is, that I have been unable to get the UI Activity Indicator to activate animation or show when user selects cell from table view.

The execution cycle looks like this:

- View loads with table view
- User clicks cell - (UIActivityIndicator fails at this step to appear or animate)
- Activity indicator appears while data is being gathered
- New view is called with the loaded data
- User clicks back button from the navigation bar
- Repeat cycle

loading object is the activity indicator link from the storyboard.

```
@synthesize jsonConnection, bakeryProductArray, bakeryTableView, loading;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self retrieveData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    loading.hidden = YES;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}


#pragma mark - UITableView DataSource

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];
    }
    else {
    return [bakeryProductArray count];

    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        foodProducts *currentProduct = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = currentProduct.productName;
    }
    else {
    foodProducts *currentProduct = [bakeryProductArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = currentProduct.productName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = currentProduct.productquantity;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;

}

#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate methods

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (bakeryTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"bakeryDetails" sender: self];
    }

        detailedViewController *productinfo = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bakeryDetails"];
        //Retrieve current user array
        foodProducts *currentProduct2 = [bakeryProductArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        productinfo.productName = currentProduct2.productName;
        productinfo.productImage = currentProduct2.productImgUrl;
        productinfo.productDescription = currentProduct2.productDescription;
        productinfo.productPrice = currentProduct2.productPrice;
        productinfo.productQuantity = currentProduct2.productquantity;
        productinfo.productAllergy = currentProduct2.productAllergy;

        [loading startAnimating];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:productinfo animated:YES];
        [bakeryTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

I have check obvious stuff like:

If the activity indicator is behind an object.
Not activating features from the IB

If you need more info, just say.

Any help would be great guys

Cheers

Comment: Is your activity indicator inside the tableViewCell or inside the View that contains your tableView? Can you see the activity indicator even if it's not spinning?

Comment: The activity indicator sits above the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if im wrong, but I can't find anywhere, where you have declared the activity indicator. Try adding this into your viewDidLoad, or where it starts animating

```
loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
loading.frame =//set frame
[self.view addSubview:loading];
//Or add it to the cell in didselectrow etc
```

Hope this helps